# Why the strings of Resources contain garbage prefixes different sizes and how to trim it?

Tags: c#, resources

I have the `TextFile1.txt` with *Hello, World!* text in my C# project. The file is saved in `UTF-8` encoding. It's file `Build action` property is `Resource` (not the `Embedded resource`).

Also I have some RESX-files with resources. I try to get string resources for each of them:

```cs
var asm = GetType().Assembly;
var name = $"{someType.FullName}.resources";
// var name = $"{asm.GetName().Name}.g.resources";

using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
using (var reader = new ResourceReader(stream)) {
    reader.GetResourceData("textfile1.txt", out string resType, out byte[] bytes);
    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
```

For different resources I get their values:

```
"\rHello, World!"
"�\u0016Command #1Command #1Command #1Command #1Command #1Command #1Command #1Command #1Command #1..."
"\rHello, World!"
"\r\0\0\0Hello, World!"
"@\v\0\0Command #2Command #2Command #2Command #2Command #2Command #2Command #2Command..."
```

The values contains garbage prefixes. The size of prefixes are not the same. I.e. I can't to skip the same size, for example `bytes.Skip(sizeof(int)).ToArray()` or `bytes.Skip(sizeof(long)).ToArray()`. Why the size of garbage prefixes are different and how can I trim it?

Comment: `\r\0\0\0` seems to be the length of the data: 0x0000000D. How did you add the file?

Comment: @shingo you are right! thank you!  It works fine: `string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.Skip(sizeof(int)).ToArray());`.

Comment: @shingo I see the offset is not constant. Different resource records can to have different offset size... I don't understand it.

Comment: Thus usually we use ResourceManager to read from .resources files.